# avrdude error - stk500_paged_write() protocol error

Tags: arduino, avr, programmer, attiny, avrdude

I am using my Arduino Uno as a programmer to program my ATtiny85. I uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch to my Uno. I double checked my wiring, did some googling, but I still can't figure out why I get this error ...

```
avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x11
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
```

... when I run this command:

```
sudo avrdude -p t85 -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 19200 -U flash:w:src.hex\
```

Then I checked to see if the ATtiny was responding, I ran this command:

```
sudo avrdude -P /dev/ttyACM0 -p t85 -b 19200 -c avrisp -v
```

The results were successful.

EDIT:

Here are the time stamps (just in case):

```
15:24:29.502445729 E: 
15:24:29.623628385 E: avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny85 
15:24:29.761744829 E: avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions 
15:24:29.766251405 E: 
15:24:29.812810614 E: Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.05s 
15:24:29.821187588 E: 
15:24:29.825324777 E: avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b 
15:24:30.171341329 E: avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed 
15:24:30.180631410 E: To disable this feature, specify the -D option. 
15:24:30.334997131 E: avrdude: erasing chip 
15:24:30.495926604 E: avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny85 
15:24:30.632387526 E: avrdude: reading input file "src.hex" 
15:24:30.637210000 E: avrdude: input file src.hex auto detected as Intel Hex 
15:24:30.641710226 E: avrdude: writing flash (98 bytes): 
15:24:30.645806835 E: 
15:24:30.712364458 E: Writing | 
15:24:30.718291473 E: avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x11 
15:24:30.752474103 E: avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync 
15:24:30.827210626 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you keep changing the -c setting?

Comment: According to the programmers.txt file in the Arduino IDE, the -c setting should be “stk500v1”, although “arduino” is very similar.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It doesn't matter if it's `arduino` or `avrisp`, they're the same thing.

Comment: @microtherion I tried `stk500v1` instead of `arduino`, the same thing happened...

Comment: I use the ISP sketch on an Uno without anti-reset components, -cstk500v1 and have no problem programm attiny85's though I'm also using -pattiny85 as the part identifier, using an avrdude config that came with an arduino installation (and specifying the path to that config with the -C option).

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried it without any reset components, that didn't work either...

Comment: Please post a picture of your setup.

Comment: Use the ArduinoISP version that is in the File => Examples => ArduinoISP

Comment: @jippie i did exactly that

Comment: Are you entirely sure that your file is valid for a tiny 85?  For example, it might try to put code at non-existent addresses.  A hex file representing 98 bytes wouldn't be too long to include in your question.

Comment: Three more things you can try: (1) Enter the interactive mode of avrdude with the `-t` flag and try some flash writes from there. (2) add some more `-v` flags, so you can see the actual ISP commands issued. (3) Try my ScratchMonkey sketch http://microtherion.github.io/ScratchMonkey/, which is pin compatible with ArduinoISP, but uses the stk500v2 protocol instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved exactly the same problem by upgrading arduino IDE  from 1.00 to 1.05 from http://code.google.com/p/arduino/downloads/list

This version of arduino IDE contains new version of ArduinoISP sketch.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error with my Arduino Uno

```
avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x11
```

I had a protoshield connected and when I disconnected the protoshield everything started working fine.

## EDIT

After some additional trouble shooting I found that it wasn't the protoshield, it was that the protoshield didn't have TX / RX marked for Digital PWM pins 0 & 1. Once I unplugged cables from 0(tx) & 1(rx) that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem: "avrdude: stk500_paged_load(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x00. avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync".

Later given up. Then I used another USB cable (proper) instead of a thin USB cable supplied with a Pololu ISP for something else and I realized the cable I used with the Arduino Nano may be of inferior quality. Changed the cable and - all my problems are solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had a long USB cable (10') connected to a powered 9-port usb hub.

Connecting directly to my mac fixed this issue immediately.

I've noticed that, depending on its mood, connecting directly to the machine can fix upload issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing "AVR-GCC Toolchain" via Homebrew fixed all this issues.

All necessary details here: http://maxembedded.com/2015/06/setting-up-avr-gcc-toolchain-on-linux-and-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect all connections on your arduino board device, and try to upload the code to your arduino board.
i solve this problem. 
There may be one of your problematic hardware, connected to your arduino board.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem: "avrdude: stk500_paged_load(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x00. avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync".

Yeah.. Then I disconnected all the connections in Bluetooth ....after I compiled the program then I connected  my Bluetooth to the Ardiuno uno.... Then I didn't get any error.